# How can I aggregate the error term of a regression to create a time series in R?

Tags: r, database, regression, aggregate

I have a dataset which includes the sales for a company in a given year (company code = gvkey, year = fyearq, sales = realsales), along with its growth rates and the volatility of these growth rates for each year. I then run a pooled regression of the volatility on the log of the age of the companies and the log of their sales by GDP, as follows:

```
pooled_reg1 <- lm(volatility ~ log_realsales_gdp + log_age, data = rs)
```

What I want to do is aggregate the error term to result in a time series matching the respective years (of fyearq). But I don't know exactly how to proceed. I know how to extract all the error terms (see below), but not how to aggregate them and match them to the years. Perhaps someone could give me some guidance?

Here is what I did to extract the residuals:

```
df_resid <- data.frame(pooled_reg1["residuals"])
```

sample of code for reproduction:

```
structure(list(gvkey = c(1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 
1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 
1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 
1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 
1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1009L, 1009L, 
1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 
1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 
1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 
1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 
1010L, 1010L, 1011L, 1011L, 1011L, 1011L, 1011L, 1011L, 1011L, 
1011L, 1011L, 1011L, 1011L, 1011L, 1011L, 1012L, 1012L, 1012L, 
1012L, 1012L, 1012L, 1012L), fyearq = c(1978L, 1979L, 1980L, 
1981L, 1982L, 1983L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 
1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 
1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 
2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 
2017L, 1981L, 1982L, 1983L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 
1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1978L, 1979L, 1980L, 
1981L, 1982L, 1983L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 
1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 
1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 1982L, 1983L, 1984L, 1985L, 
1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 
1978L, 1979L, 1980L, 1981L, 1982L, 1983L, 1984L), realsales = c(331.462808301444, 
336.893554460808, 313.396257658553, 380.187150173968, 315.488887079704, 
348.170636164212, 413.902226927294, 454.475820490737, 535.642177115143, 
609.402937979876, 688.057705006858, 724.859060840095, 732.738609414019, 
642.091910368401, 568.555514296324, 591.633778293674, 641.258949880668, 
702.663215895809, 805.279914734296, 1050.60514473773, 1219.44662141519, 
1341.27667932434, 1119.72002356618, 800.502569244266, 748.083946108671, 
789.706505808108, 882.10426987497, 1026.39411583029, 1178.21264406102, 
1497.4363687477, 1510.28901734104, 1423.25691549829, 1847.63658686311, 
2114.28891742596, 2167.1, 1999.90172473097, 1537.71219135802, 
1586.61691589766, 1668.57034974277, 1619.57609219254, 95.3190845633523, 
73.2923552877961, 36.7302569727358, 39.734961624258, 37.5785673709479, 
34.6075085324232, 34.270588647758, 48.1196769332363, 59.2856910092221, 
63.642788710716, 55.0277250284846, 76.3564797623468, 104.991294254208, 
130.869985225594, 2304.25127789727, 2557.85251863506, 2471.17782035815, 
2029.46642750632, 1598.19058861842, 1129.41280162958, 393.050776966993, 
390.214582837038, 362.651338243219, 409.53966974021, 487.178922772143, 
531.902760126438, 490.504311224891, 461.968856817319, 475.526178982547, 
505.55571677307, 540.544380043187, 566.594311793844, 665.181804517443, 
674.188998589563, 712.64428888328, 618.567500327354, 568.405953021338, 
459.330743200902, 386.541973054335, 2833.31516406846, 6.65961084425629, 
7.50156690692573, 8.62414458013536, 10.7511315533892, 8.39051553799174, 
4.76983487010483, 4.38375184137896, 5.35568807638414, 5.70903551067205, 
6.78313710596278, 6.9275900482733, 9.41671503192107, 25.2003068530515, 
29.9265383648501, 29.3079879291223, 25.2383317957088, 34.024160957794, 
31.3705935032158, 37.34135067377, 41.6783243222806), volatility = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.00665816567008701, 0.0324276719081096, 0.0011761305418464, 
0.0373049165276953, 0.0226152181777751, 0.0218762758245523, 0.0012925667201047, 
0.012111784694849, 0.053640253681283, 0.0560154015587973, 0.00796354785350488, 
0.00425711461807538, 0.0135804572895571, 0.0345848107430184, 
0.0831895974216554, 0.0371968284679624, 0.0169218179069936, 0.0690514385917552, 
0.107027521719637, 0.0365165087945687, 0.00659596088012272, 0.0309824937544606, 
0.0310571504387218, 0.0125259197780714, 0.0485690814477484, 0.0301958815208215, 
0.0401249106117258, 0.0765562587730122, 0.0309473259041627, 0.00270426776564803, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.0181423079224915, 0.0157836589437877, 
0.0874516492044545, 0.0278328374322155, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.0605200436913354, 0.173363757329929, 0.0319203280203071, 
0.00805233255502984, 0.0636274273545883, 0.0714183125006309, 
0.0176928889665883, 0.0377017769049437, 0.0392223624595263, 0.00788488747413858, 
0.00699585791401976, 0.0159892018789829, 0.00944642764433993, 
0.0534590734296324, 0.00865661592365628, 0.175760113935155, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.145559788349328, 0.0420615646568418, 
0.00537514475672203, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
0.0348308867716433, 0.00318295127858273), log_age = c(1.69897000433602, 
1.69897000433602, 1.69897000433602, 1.69897000433602, 1.69897000433602, 
1.69897000433602, 1.69897000433602, 1.69897000433602, 1.69897000433602, 
1.69897000433602, 1.69897000433602, 1.69897000433602, 1.69897000433602, 
1.69897000433602, 1.69897000433602, 1.69897000433602, 1.69897000433602, 
1.69897000433602, 1.69897000433602, 1.69897000433602, 1.69897000433602, 
1.69897000433602, 1.69897000433602, 1.69897000433602, 1.69897000433602, 
1.69897000433602, 1.69897000433602, 1.69897000433602, 1.69897000433602, 
1.69897000433602, 1.69897000433602, 1.69897000433602, 1.69897000433602, 
1.69897000433602, 1.69897000433602, 1.69897000433602, 1.69897000433602, 
1.69897000433602, 1.69897000433602, 1.69897000433602, 1.07918124604762, 
1.07918124604762, 1.07918124604762, 1.07918124604762, 1.07918124604762, 
1.07918124604762, 1.07918124604762, 1.07918124604762, 1.07918124604762, 
1.07918124604762, 1.07918124604762, 1.07918124604762, 1.07918124604762, 
1.07918124604762, 1.6232492903979, 1.6232492903979, 1.6232492903979, 
1.6232492903979, 1.6232492903979, 1.6232492903979, 1.6232492903979, 
1.6232492903979, 1.6232492903979, 1.6232492903979, 1.6232492903979, 
1.6232492903979, 1.6232492903979, 1.6232492903979, 1.6232492903979, 
1.6232492903979, 1.6232492903979, 1.6232492903979, 1.6232492903979, 
1.6232492903979, 1.6232492903979, 1.6232492903979, 1.6232492903979, 
1.6232492903979, 1.6232492903979, 1.6232492903979, 1.11394335230684, 
1.11394335230684, 1.11394335230684, 1.11394335230684, 1.11394335230684, 
1.11394335230684, 1.11394335230684, 1.11394335230684, 1.11394335230684, 
1.11394335230684, 1.11394335230684, 1.11394335230684, 1.11394335230684, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 
0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944, 0.903089986991944), log_realsales_gdp = c(-3.85092846126199, 
-3.89202258398861, -3.95986309900425, -3.92610721336975, -4.02525479868339, 
-4.01859732325605, -3.98922692698506, -3.97987676584237, -3.93195571993198, 
-3.90130392256075, -3.88141110327525, -3.89114717898222, -3.91052622100324, 
-3.98185158389712, -4.05949650050273, -4.0641799176444, -4.05552939505513, 
-4.03633187127866, -4.00109464846784, -3.91192383639405, -3.87110041585158, 
-3.85613781251219, -3.96171385223621, -4.12119772171715, -4.16492476613527, 
-4.16165242613348, -4.14132839082574, -4.1038514193103, -4.06911491834599, 
-3.98457536898222, -3.98863659543405, -4.00655244449318, -3.9092445263483, 
-3.86635883397372, -3.87355581774889, -3.92390883541018, -4.05670234760785, 
-4.06005953525173, -4.04966401200689, -4.08030783458173, -4.52692478479852, 
-4.65918018655632, -4.99536549750444, -5.0069518921217, -5.06244732898982, 
-5.12166015184978, -5.15128690208025, -5.03671326290263, -4.97845086481487, 
-4.97172609557892, -5.04886722376997, -4.93142347847181, -4.81507958954762, 
-4.74572278116639, -3.00883342982249, -3.0116397858153, -3.0630529077774, 
-3.19872277617792, -3.32061029587535, -3.50753675822248, -4.01167603092783, 
-4.04608405269173, -4.10134120207404, -4.07391249049084, -4.03134747501897, 
-4.02556850705364, -4.08483246805255, -4.12483608322756, -4.13709494552001, 
-4.1324638532487, -4.12973147813548, -4.12980688009274, -4.08410115458261, 
-4.1045816981461, -4.10439040157307, -4.19226908778151, -4.25616467912613, 
-4.36243493795575, -4.45167844188923, -3.60682325599905, -5.70079001292832, 
-5.68523747715828, -5.67040866136935, -5.60593337219298, -5.73704184051214, 
-6.00770512203238, -6.07719000449261, -6.0225854759125, -6.01891255259848, 
-5.95801818678252, -5.973687196852, -5.86233345093503, -5.46115700552331, 
-4.89530678240497, -4.95252928201182, -5.05389625964478, -4.97431722334064, 
-5.02771612951806, -4.98819944151722, -4.98621444021067)), row.names = c(NA, 
100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses `dplyr`'s `left_join`.

```
dplyr::left_join(rs, with(pooled_reg1, cbind(model, residuals)))
```

This extracts the residuals and binds them to the data used in the model using `cbind`. (Note that not all data are used because of `NA`s in some columns.) `left_join` then joins this data frame to the original data frame. This gives,

```
Joining, by = c("volatility", "log_age", "log_realsales_gdp")
#      gvkey fyearq   realsales  volatility  log_age log_realsales_gdp     residuals
# 1    1004   1978  331.462808          NA 1.698970         -3.850928            NA
# 2    1004   1979  336.893554          NA 1.698970         -3.892023            NA
# 3    1004   1980  313.396258          NA 1.698970         -3.959863            NA
# 4    1004   1981  380.187150          NA 1.698970         -3.926107            NA
# 5    1004   1982  315.488887          NA 1.698970         -4.025255            NA
# 6    1004   1983  348.170636 0.006658166 1.698970         -4.018597 -3.171299e-02
# 7    1004   1984  413.902227 0.032427672 1.698970         -3.989227 -5.543927e-03
# 8    1004   1985  454.475820 0.001176131 1.698970         -3.979877 -3.666827e-02
# 9    1004   1986  535.642177 0.037304917 1.698970         -3.931956  1.124336e-04
# 10   1004   1987  609.402938 0.022615218 1.698970         -3.901304 -1.416028e-02
# 11   1004   1988  688.057705 0.021876276 1.698970         -3.881411 -1.462860e-02
# 12   1004   1989  724.859061 0.001292567 1.698970         -3.891147 -3.534476e-02
# 13   1004   1990  732.738609 0.012111785 1.698970         -3.910526 -2.478917e-02
# 14   1004   1991  642.091910 0.053640254 1.698970         -3.981852  1.576899e-02
# 15   1004   1992  568.555514 0.056015402 1.698970         -4.059497  1.708786e-02
# 16   1004   1993  591.633778 0.007963548 1.698970         -4.064180 -3.102771e-02
# 17   1004   1994  641.258950 0.004257115 1.698970         -4.055529 -3.461646e-02
# 18   1004   1995  702.663216 0.013580457 1.698970         -4.036332 -2.503196e-02
# 19   1004   1996  805.279915 0.034584811 1.698970         -4.001095 -3.548236e-03
# 20   1004   1997 1050.605145 0.083189597 1.698970         -3.911924  4.626963e-02
# 21   1004   1998 1219.446621 0.037196828 1.698970         -3.871100  8.322195e-04
# 22   1004   1999 1341.276679 0.016921818 1.698970         -3.856138 -1.923924e-02
# 23   1004   2000 1119.720024 0.069051439 1.698970         -3.961714  3.145413e-02
# 24   1004   2001  800.502569 0.107027522 1.698970         -4.121198  6.726060e-02
# 25   1004   2002  748.083946 0.036516509 1.698970         -4.164925 -3.845279e-03
# 26   1004   2003  789.706506 0.006595961 1.698970         -4.161652 -3.372131e-02
# 27   1004   2004  882.104270 0.030982494 1.698970         -4.141328 -9.058290e-03
# 28   1004   2005 1026.394116 0.031057150 1.698970         -4.103851 -8.473797e-03
# 29   1004   2006 1178.212644 0.012525920 1.698970         -4.069115 -2.653247e-02
# 30   1004   2007 1497.436369 0.048569081 1.698970         -3.984575  1.066076e-02
# 31   1004   2008 1510.289017 0.030195882 1.698970         -3.988637 -7.767687e-03
# 32   1004   2009 1423.256915 0.040124911 1.698970         -4.006552  1.917616e-03
# 33   1004   2010 1847.636587 0.076556259 1.698970         -3.909245  3.967274e-02
# 34   1004   2011 2114.288917 0.030947326 1.698970         -3.866359 -5.352779e-03
# 35   1004   2012 2167.100000 0.002704268 1.698970         -3.873556 -3.369374e-02
# 36   1004   2013 1999.901725          NA 1.698970         -3.923909            NA
# 37   1004   2014 1537.712191          NA 1.698970         -4.056702            NA
# 38   1004   2015 1586.616916          NA 1.698970         -4.060060            NA
# 39   1004   2016 1668.570350          NA 1.698970         -4.049664            NA
# 40   1004   2017 1619.576092          NA 1.698970         -4.080308            NA
# 41   1009   1981   95.319085          NA 1.079181         -4.526925            NA
# 42   1009   1982   73.292355          NA 1.079181         -4.659180            NA
# 43   1009   1983   36.730257          NA 1.079181         -4.995365            NA
# 44   1009   1984   39.734962          NA 1.079181         -5.006952            NA
# 45   1009   1985   37.578567          NA 1.079181         -5.062447            NA
# 46   1009   1986   34.607509 0.018142308 1.079181         -5.121660 -2.252609e-02
# 47   1009   1987   34.270589 0.015783659 1.079181         -5.151287 -2.528778e-02
# 48   1009   1988   48.119677 0.087451649 1.079181         -5.036713  4.793887e-02
# 49   1009   1989   59.285691 0.027832837 1.079181         -4.978451 -1.088734e-02
# 50   1009   1990   63.642789          NA 1.079181         -4.971726            NA
# 51   1009   1991   55.027725          NA 1.079181         -5.048867            NA
# 52   1009   1992   76.356480          NA 1.079181         -4.931423            NA
# 53   1009   1993  104.991294          NA 1.079181         -4.815080            NA
# 54   1009   1994  130.869985          NA 1.079181         -4.745723            NA
# 55   1010   1978 2304.251278          NA 1.623249         -3.008833            NA
# 56   1010   1979 2557.852519          NA 1.623249         -3.011640            NA
# 57   1010   1980 2471.177820          NA 1.623249         -3.063053            NA
# 58   1010   1981 2029.466428          NA 1.623249         -3.198723            NA
# 59   1010   1982 1598.190589          NA 1.623249         -3.320610            NA
# 60   1010   1983 1129.412802 0.060520044 1.623249         -3.507537  3.065400e-02
# 61   1010   1984  393.050777 0.173363757 1.623249         -4.011676  1.366394e-01
# 62   1010   1985  390.214583 0.031920328 1.623249         -4.046084 -5.272097e-03
# 63   1010   1986  362.651338 0.008052333 1.623249         -4.101341 -2.989181e-02
# 64   1010   1987  409.539670 0.063627427 1.623249         -4.073912  2.605642e-02
# 65   1010   1988  487.178923 0.071418313 1.623249         -4.031347  3.442636e-02
# 66   1010   1989  531.902760 0.017692889 1.623249         -4.025569 -1.922044e-02
# 67   1010   1990  490.504311 0.037701777 1.623249         -4.084832 -1.778101e-05
# 68   1010   1991  461.968857 0.039222362 1.623249         -4.124836  9.585964e-04
# 69   1010   1992  475.526179 0.007884887 1.623249         -4.137095 -3.054565e-02
# 70   1010   1993  505.555717 0.006995858 1.623249         -4.132464 -3.137168e-02
# 71   1010   1994  540.544380 0.015989202 1.623249         -4.129731 -2.234116e-02
# 72   1010   1995  566.594312 0.009446428 1.623249         -4.129807 -2.888496e-02
# 73   1010   1996  665.181805 0.053459073 1.623249         -4.084101  1.574946e-02
# 74   1010   1997  674.188999 0.008656616 1.623249         -4.104582 -2.933161e-02
# 75   1010   1998  712.644289 0.175760114 1.623249         -4.104390  1.377745e-01
# 76   1010   1999  618.567500          NA 1.623249         -4.192269            NA
# 77   1010   2000  568.405953          NA 1.623249         -4.256165            NA
# 78   1010   2001  459.330743          NA 1.623249         -4.362435            NA
# 79   1010   2002  386.541973          NA 1.623249         -4.451678            NA
# 80   1010   2003 2833.315164          NA 1.623249         -3.606823            NA
# 81   1011   1982    6.659611          NA 1.113943         -5.700790            NA
# 82   1011   1983    7.501567          NA 1.113943         -5.685237            NA
# 83   1011   1984    8.624145          NA 1.113943         -5.670409            NA
# 84   1011   1985   10.751132          NA 1.113943         -5.605933            NA
# 85   1011   1986    8.390516          NA 1.113943         -5.737042            NA
# 86   1011   1987    4.769835 0.145559788 1.113943         -6.007705  9.212486e-02
# 87   1011   1988    4.383752 0.042061565 1.113943         -6.077190 -1.231863e-02
# 88   1011   1989    5.355688 0.005375145 1.113943         -6.022585 -4.826222e-02
# 89   1011   1990    5.709036          NA 1.113943         -6.018913            NA
# 90   1011   1991    6.783137          NA 1.113943         -5.958018            NA
# 91   1011   1992    6.927590          NA 1.113943         -5.973687            NA
# 92   1011   1993    9.416715          NA 1.113943         -5.862333            NA
# 93   1011   1994   25.200307          NA 1.113943         -5.461157            NA
# 94   1012   1978   29.926538          NA 0.903090         -4.895307            NA
# 95   1012   1979   29.307988          NA 0.903090         -4.952529            NA
# 96   1012   1980   25.238332          NA 0.903090         -5.053896            NA
# 97   1012   1981   34.024161          NA 0.903090         -4.974317            NA
# 98   1012   1982   31.370594          NA 0.903090         -5.027716            NA
# 99   1012   1983   37.341351 0.034830887 0.903090         -4.988199 -4.111560e-04
# 100  1012   1984   41.678324 0.003182951 0.903090         -4.986214 -3.203209e-02
```

---

One caveat is that this relies on unique combinations of `volatility`, `log_age`, and `log_realsales_gdp`. If this is not a guarantee, then a more prolix but more robust solution is,

```
library(dplyr)

rs %>% 
  select(fyearq, volatility, log_age,log_realsales_gdp) %>% 
  na.omit %>% 
  cbind(pooled_reg1$residuals) %>% 
  right_join(rs)
```